# Dependency 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.28.0' not found

Tags: maven, apache-beam

I think my JAVA environments are not set correctly.
I ran this command

```
mvn clean install
```

Getting this error
***Dependency 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.28.0' not found***

Here is the POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipleine-project-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <beam.version>2.28.0</beam.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @glytching, do you have time to take a look at this error?

Comment: Could you provide the full log of your build and the command how you run it?

Comment: mvn clean install

Comment: Do you have something else in the output?